# Can't login to ubuntu-16.04.5-server-i386 GUI with correct password on windows 8.1 virtaul machine unable to login to GUI with correct password

Tags: 16.04, server, login, password

Password - There are no words

Login Password - There are no words Problem in Ubuntu server 16.04.5 LTS GUI

[image Can't login to ubuntu-16.04.5-server-i386 GUI with correct password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ghjr.png)

[on windows 8.1 virtaul machine unable to login to GUI with correct password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cyk3Q.png)

Answer (score 2):

In the Linux console (or any *nix console for that matter) you will find this. It is a way of hiding the input of a password..

In Windows, we can see a similar practice:

[image]

Just enter your password and press return.